# Control does not exist in the current context in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
  private void BindSubjectData()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select *from GroupMaster";

            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            ddlGroup.DataSource = dt;
            ddlGroup.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlGroup.DataTextField = "GroupName";
            ddlGroup.DataBind();
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

> Design part

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgroup" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm using jquery script in asp.net. If i bind any values to a dropdownlist control, I'm getting this isuse `"The name 'ddlGroup' does not exist in the current context "`. But I'm used to design dropdownlist control in design page.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.  It will make it easier to debug.

Comment: Please put your code here.

Comment: The above error clearly states that, its looking for a control with id="ddlGroup", so either you have missed to given runat="server" while defining Dropdown. Showing your dropdown code might help in debuging your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropdown ID in Design part is `ddlgroup` but in your code behind you are using  `ddlGroup`  so that is the reason for the Error.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik What do you mean by `automatically changed` ?